# Calculate a score between 2 variables

Tags: statistics

We run a private education center. For a back-end application we want to generate an algorithm which gives a real-time score to every course we organise, based on occupancy and date.

We have 2 variables:

1. Days remaining before course (starting from 100 to 0 days > or 100 to 0%)
2. Occupancy percentage (0 to 100%)

What we now want is a formule which gives us a real time score 0 to 100% for each course by which it tells us how well it is performing.

First variable (days remaining before course) is starting at 100% and second variable (occupancy percentage) is starting at 0%. As the occupancy starts to rise and days remaining before course are decreasing, the score will change daily.

Let's say we are 40 days from the course date and we have an occupancy of 70%. How would we give this course a score? Knowing that 100% occupancy with 100 to 0 days remaining is a score of 100%. The score should increase as the occupancy rises and decrease as the days remaining are decreasing.

Which formule would do the trick?

Comment: There are a lot of formulas that would satisfy the given requirements. What is the purpose of this score? That might give some clues about what would make one formula better than another.

Answer (score 0):

Let's represent $S$ as the score, $O$ as the occupancy percentage, and $D$ as the days remaining divided by 100.

You want $S = 1$ when $O = 1$ regardless of $D$, but also that $S$ increases as $O$ increases and $S$ decreases as $D$ decreases.

A simple solution that satisfies those constraints would then just be
$$
S = O^n + (1-O^n)D
$$
for some value $n$ that you can tweak to suit your weighting needs (make it higher if you care more about occupancy and lower if you care more about the days remaining).